# Hide an Icon from the Solution Explorer Window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I want to hide (or disable) for example the 'Refresh' icon in the Solution Explorer window
[alt text http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/8421/16520725.png](http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/8421/16520725.png)

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think so. Why did you want to hide anyway?

Comment: actually it's not this window and not this icon, it's window of some third party application and one of the icons their makes troubles once clicked. but I guess it acts exactly the same as the solution explorer window.